# Installing extras using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When writing a `setup.py` I can specify `extras_require` and give a list of dependencies that are needed for additional functionality of my tool like this:

```
setup(
    name = "mypackage",
    install_requires = ["numpy"],
    extras_require = {
        "plotting": ["matplotlib"],
    }
)
```

I uploaded my package to PyPI and a conda channel and tried to install it, including all extras. From PyPI I can install the extras using:

```
$ pip install mypackage[plotting]
```

However, when installing my package from conda, I fail to install the extras. Is there a similar option for conda?

Comment: This is not currently possible, see: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3299 and https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2984

The solution that I use is just to make everything that you might use a dependency.

Comment: Thanks. This, unfortunately, answers my question. I will keep an eye on the Issue and meanwhile rewrite my documentation. Would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 18-APR-2017, this is not currently possible. See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3299 and https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2984

The solution that I generally use is just to make everything that might be optional as a mandatory dependency. This tends to work out, since conda packages are available for most platforms, particularly for common dependencies, and if a dependency isn't available, writing a conda recipe and uploading it to Anaconda.org is relatively easy.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by creating a metapackage for the optional dependency. A good example for this is the [matploptlib-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/matplotlib-feedstock/blob/5af510232c2fa984e981e3eeb18128a6cab41b6d/recipe/meta.yaml#L69-L82). Here you have the main package `matplotlib-base` that contains all code and the metapackage `matplotlib` that depends on `matplotlib-base` and its optional Qt dependencies.

With the `matplotlib` example in mind, you could have the following outputs in your recipe:

```
package:
  name: some_pkg

…usual recipe contents…

outputs:
  - name: some_pkg

  - name: some_pkg_with_optional_dep
    requirements:
      host:
        - python
      run:
        - python
        - optional_dependency
        - {{ pin_subpackage('some_pkg', exact=True) }}
    test:
      imports:
        - some_pkg
```

Note that when you require a specific version of an optional dependency, you can specify it in the optional package but then the version constraint will only be applied when you have `some_pkg_with_optional_dep` installed.

To have the version constraint on the optional dependency respected independently of the presence of `some_pkg_with_optional_dep`, you should specify it in the `run_constrained` section:

```
requirements:
  …
  run_constraint:
    - optional_dependency >=1.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice, this looks like a very clean way to solve my problem.

Comment: Metapackages are suboptimal for this purpose, see this feature request for the reason: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7502

Comment: You should not name the top level package name the same as the name of one of the outputs since conda-build has a bug where stuff breaks if the names clash, see https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3933.

`package: name: some_pkg-split` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this syntax may help:

Since pip can do
`python -m pip install 'some-package[extra] @ git+https://git.repo/SomePackage@main'`

We can have in the environment.yaml:

```
- pip
   - some-package[extra] @ git+https://git.repo/SomePackage@main
```

Using this may help you build the recipe you need for your conda package to use the package with the extras you want.
[pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples)